# Check if lead is known, then based on email address redirect to page

Tags: javascript, marketo

Let me start by stating that I am a beginner in Javascript and I have tried to construct my own code from reading different similar solutions here.

I am creating a 2 step verification in marketo, step one check if the lead is known, step 2 If the lead is known then check if their email address is from an accepted domain to proceed (e.g only leads from the domain marketo.com are allowed to proceed.)

I started by creating a verification landing page, I created a form and hid the submit button, created a rich text field and set an error message (for unknown leads).

Then created a hidden Email field with prefill enabled

Then in the form settings I selected 'If lead is known' option and in the custom HTML, put the following logic

```
<script>
var allowedEmail = '@marketo.';
if (allowedEmail.indexOf(mktoPreFillFields.Email) != -1) {
window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/Valid_Email.html");}
  else {
   window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/Invalid_Email.html");}
</script>
```

But its not working, Any known lead (using a marketo.com or any other recognised email in marketo) is going to the Invalid_Email page, any idea's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the opposite.

Right now, you are checking if *@marketo.* contains (for example) *example@marketo.com.*

You should check if *example@marketo.com* contains *@marketo.*.

```
var allowedEmail = '@marketo.';
if (mktoPrefillFields.Email.indexOf(allowedEmail) != -1) {
    window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/Valid_Email.html");
}
else {
    window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/Invalid_Email.html");
}
```

Comment: I tried this code, and the page now does not redirect at all. (nothing happens)

Comment: Works fine for me. Tested it on a JSFiddle 30s ago. Replace your window.location by alert to see if it goes in any of the block (maybe your code crash before).

Comment: Just discovered there is a Typo in the prefill field - mktoPreFillFields.Email now works thanks!

Comment: Woops! Indeed, I made a dummy variable instead of this one for the test,didn't notice that typo, sorry! Glad your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I think k it should be (mktoPreFillFields.Email.indexOf(allowedEmails) != -1

Comment: var allowedEmail = "@marketo.";
if (mktoPrefilLFields.Email.indexOf(allowedEmail) != -1) {
    window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/Valid_Email.html");
}
else {
    window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/Invalid_Email.html");
}

tried this code, did not work, nothing happens